# magento select all the products which have special price

Tags: magento-1.9, product, database, special-price

I want to select all the products `SKU` which have special price 
through `mysql` query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Magento 1.9. Here `76` is `attribute_id` for `special_price` attribute.**

```
select cpe.sku,cpe.type_id, cped.store_id, cped.value from catalog_product_entity_decimal cped
RIGHT OUTER JOIN catalog_product_entity cpe on cpe.entity_id = cped.entity_id 
where cped.attribute_id=76
order by cpe.type_id
```

Comment: But this won't be the applied final price, need to check the dates also.

Answer (score 2):

here is mysql query (please note that table name can contain prefixes)

```
select e.sku,pd.store_id, pd.value from catalog_product_entity as e 
inner join  catalog_product_entity_decimal as pd on e.entity_id = pd.entity_id 
inner join eav_attribute as a on pd.attribute_id = a.attribute_id 
where a.attribute_code="special_price"
```

Answer (score 2):

Below code works perfectly for me.

`SELECT e.sku,pd.store_id, pd.value FROM catalog_product_entity AS e`

`INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS pd ON e.entity_id = pd.entity_id`

`INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS a ON pd.attribute_id = a.attribute_id`

`WHERE a.attribute_code="special_price"`